# How to instantiate a generic class that extends Number with a given double value?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have this `Foo` class, which has generic type variable `E` that extends `Number`. Since each `Number` object should have a double value, when instantiating a new instance of type `E` I would like to give it a double value. Is it possible? How?

```
public class Foo<E extends Number> {
    ...
    public void someMethod() {
        ... // some computation
        Class<E> typeClass;
        E newInstance = typeClass.newInstance();
        // Because every Number has a doubleValue(),
        // I would like to give newInstance a double value, how?
    }
}
```

Or should I just abandon the generic type variable, and use `Double` instead? But I don't want to limit user's freedom of using `Byte` or `Integer`. Are these number classes interchangeable, i.e., can `Byte` cast to `Double` in some way?

Thanks!!

EDIT:

I am implementing Dijkstra's algorithm with generics, which calculates the least weighted path. This means the edge labels can be accumulated in some way, and the most general class for this purpose that I can think of is `Number`.

Comment: Why do you want to instantiate a new instance in the first place?

Comment: I think you need to give some more information about what your class does.

Comment: Because I need to add a new element to a collection, and I need to construct that element. Is this acceptable?

Comment: Why do you need to add a new element without the user passing you an element to add?

Comment: I've edited the question about why I would like to do this.

Comment: `typeClass.newInstance()` won't work because `Double` does not have a constructor without arguments. You almost certainly don't need generics or reflection. I would just use `double`s for now.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense if the user passed you the weights for the edges there would not need to create new number objects.

Comment: There's typically no user that passes edges to the Dijkstra's algorithm. Yet I think using `Double` instead of `Number` is probably the solution here.

Comment: @zsfly `Number` doesn't offer much. It's supposed to represent a generic number, but doesn't have any methods for the things you can usually do with a number, such as `add`, `multiply` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your assumption that

> Since each Number object should have a double value, when instantiating a new instance of type E I would like to give it a double value.

is not correct.

For example, how can you instantiate a Integer with a double value 1.5? Should it instantiate by rounding? By truncating? I can very well define a subclass of Number that doesn't even support arbitrary integer, like the following one:

```
public static class Zero extends Number {
    @Override
    public double doubleValue() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public float floatValue() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int intValue() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long longValue() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How do you instantiate a Zero with a double value like 1.5?

Since there is no universal logic that can instantiate an arbitrary subclass of Number with an arbitrary double value (this is the reason why Number don't have an constructor with a double argument), the only reasonable way is to ask the client to provide a **factory** that can fabricate an instance of a subclass of Number given an arbitrary double value with custom logic that applies to that specific subclass. Like the following:

```
  public class Foo<E extends Number> {

    public static interface NumberFactory<T extends Number> {
        T createByDoubleValue(double value);
    }

    private final NumberFactory<E> factory;

    public Foo(NumberFactory<E> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    ...
    public void someMethod() {
      ... // some computation
      // Because every Number has a doubleValue(),
      // I would like to give newInstance a double value, how?
      E instance = factory.createByDoubleValue(1.5);
    }
  }
```

To use Foo class, the client need to define the factory, like the following:

```
Foo<Float> foo = new Foo<>(new Foo.NumberFactory<Float>() {
  @Override
    public Float createByDoubleValue(double value) {
      return new Float(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: That being said, for the sake of implementing Dijkstra's algorithm, there is no need to generalize the weight type to be Number. Since you need to eventually adding and comparing the weights, you need to convert them to double values anyway. There is really no difference between doing it yourself and asking the user to call Number.doubleValue()..